# Match only letters and special characters with RegExp

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

How can I allow only letters and special characters with a regular expression?

Comment: What's your definition of a "special character"?

Comment: what are "special characters"? Can you provide more of a use case with perhaps some examples?

Comment: is '!@#$%¨&*()-=+/*.{} and all characters that not is number

Comment: ER = Regular Expression , Expression Regular, RegEXP

Comment: @XMLP4rse: The space is a character that is not a number.

Comment: @XMLP4rse: Really? I never knew.

Comment: So you want everything except numbers?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [GSkinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)'s REGEX builder and experiment with a lot of the examples on the right hand side. There are are many variations to get this job done. If you want to be explicit you can use:

```
/[a-zA-Z!@#$%¨&*()-=+/*.{}]/
```

Tony's answer will also work, but includes more extra characters than the ones you've defined in your comment.

Comment: ok, how i can do to check if not cotains letters and numbers , or only letters in htaccess ?

Comment: combine this with @anubhava's response... or just use @anubhava's response, because his works too.

Comment: how i can do ? , 0 - 9 [ valid ] , 5q216.54q321 [ invalid ] , qaglçzg [ invalid ] , anything with strings is invalid .. how i can do ? if have only numbers, is valid, if have only string, or string + numbers is invalid ..

Comment: a single number? **/[0-9]/** ... 
n number of numbers **/[0-9]{n}/**

Answer (score 1):

This

```
        $str = $_REQUEST["htmlstringinput"];
        preg_match("([\w\-]+[@#%.])", $str);
```

for letters, numbers and special characters in this special character range `[@#%.]` are allowed

and this

```
       $str = $_REQUEST["htmlstringinput"];
       preg_match("([-a-zA-Z]+[@#%.])", $str);
```

for only letters and special characters in the same special character range as above
Worked for me. For further reading and research you can go to : http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

```
/[\p{L}\p{P}]+/u
```

matches letters and punctuation characters. Or what did you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: RewriteRule ^user/([a-z]|[A-Z].*)$ index.php?goto=missed [NC]

i trying to block user use numbers at URL .. all that not is number is allowed, some 1 can help ?

Answer (score 0):

all characters not a number?  how bout this:

```
/[^\d]*/
```

Comment: can you be more specific. It is just a regex that will match on any string not containing digits, including a blank string.  There's not a lot to "not work" there.  Can you show me how you are using it?

Comment: how i can do ? , 0 - 9 [ valid ] , 5q216.54q321 [ invalid ] , qaglçzg [ invalid ] , anything with strings is invalid .. how i can do ? if have only numbers, is valid, if have only string, or string + numbers is invalid ..

Comment: `/[\d]*/` match on ONLY all digit subjects

Comment: how i can apply in htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in .htaccess to block all URLs with number (as per OP's comments)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![0-9] 
RewriteRule ^user/ /index.php?goto=missed [NC,L]
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no other code/rule overstepping this? When I tested URI `/user/ab,c` it goes internally to `/index.php?goto=missed` There is no blocking of comma in above code anyway. All it is saying if there NO numeral in URI then apply following rule.