# Regular Expression for only certain characters

Tags: php, regex

I was wondering if someone knew of a website with a lot of regular express examples?

How do I modify this this statement white to my understanding allows only alphanumeric and spaces, to also include: ,.?! `'" ;:  -_=+ /| @#$%^&*

```
$output = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $input);
```

Comment: Check out this website: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow Some Special Characters using Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503278/allow-some-special-characters-using-regex)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match only letters and special characters with RegExp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886910/match-only-letters-and-special-characters-with-regexp)

Comment: And here is how you use the Google to find things: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20regex%20allow%20some%20characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern itself **disallows** letters, digits and spaces, but the command removes anything that is "allowed", so the command leaves only those characters. Anyway, this would include the other characters as well:

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ,.?!`\'";:_=+\/|@#$%^&*-]/', "", $input);
```

Check out both the tutorial and the examples section of [this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)!

Comment: How would I also add brackets? `[]` And also `line breaks`?

Comment: You can simply add `[` to the character group. You could also just add `]` if you do it right after the `^`, but it might be better to put it anywhere else and escape it with `\ `. Line breaks are `\r` and `\n`. Read the section on character classes on the linked website. But here you go: `'/[^A-Za-z0-9 ,.?!\`\'";:_=+\/|@#$%^&*[\]\r\n-]/'`

Answer (score 3):

This website - www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html provides systematic way of learning RegExp. You can also use expresso to practice regex....however the usablity of regex defers from language to language. This website - www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html provides you a good base.